# Android Spinner. White text on black background

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

Help!!!
**Spinner 1:**
here is the xml of  the Spinner I have, Its with white background and black text color for the items. I want it to have a Black Background with  white text.

**XML:**
`<Spinner android:id="@+id/categorySpinner" android:layout_width="369dp" android:layout_height="41dp" android:layout_margin="12dp" android:spinnerMode="dropdown" android:entries="@array/category_items" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#FFFFFF" />`

**Java:**
`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> categoryAdapter =      ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getApplicationContext(), R.array.category_items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); categoryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); categorySpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter); categorySpinner.setSelection(0, false); // Set the hint item as selected`

Note: The attribute **android:textColor="#000000"** is not working for this.

**Spinner 2**
For the 2nd Spinner below, I want it to have a rounded black color border .
**XML:**
`<Spinner android:id="@+id/conditionSpinner" android:layout_width="369dp" android:layout_height="41dp" android:layout_margin="12dp" android:spinnerMode="dropdown" android:entries="@array/condition_items" android:paddingLeft="16dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:background="@drawable/spinner_border" />`

**Java:**
`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> conditionAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.condition_items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); conditionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); conditionSpinner.setAdapter(conditionAdapter); conditionSpinner.setSelection(0, false); // Set the hint item as selected`

For Spinner 1, I want it to have a Black Background with white text.
For Spinner 2, I want it to have a black rounded border

Comment: spinner inner view is populated by adapter you set on it, hance you can't set textColor on it. You use there android.R.layout - you can make your own copy of that layout and make changes in it to make text color change, or overwrite attributes in theme to change it

Comment: I am here for a solution. Please provide me with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((TextView) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                if (position == 0){
                    Luxury();//code for Luxury 
                }
                else if (position == 1){
                    Tech();//code for Tech
                }
                else if (position == 2){
                    Clothes();//code for Clothes
                }
                else if (position == 2){
                    Furniture();//code for Furniture
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```